# Ajustando Footer após migrar para Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estava usando o Boostrap 3 e migrei para o 4, só que algumas coisas quebraram. Consegui resolver algumas, mas estou com problema com esse footer.

```
 <div class="copyright">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <p>© Copyright  @DateTime.Now.Year.- LMS/US-LOG/OLNF/TM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul class="bottom_ul">
                    <li><a target="_blank">GISSUB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SGMAR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Suporte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Chamados</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Recursos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 .bottom_ul { list-style-type:none; float:right; margin-bottom:0px;}
 .bottom_ul li { float:left; line-height:40px;}
 .bottom_ul li:after { content:"/"; color:#FFF; margin-right:8px; margin-left:8px;}
 .bottom_ul li a { color:#FFF;  font-size:12px;}
```

Como vcs podem ver na imagem abaixo, eles não estão alinhados.
Como eu faria para deixar essas divs na mesma linha e a div da direita alinhada a direita da tela?

[image: FOOTER]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está com alguns problemainhas.

Primeiro a `div` *copyright* não está fechada. Depois a sua `div` class `row` está no lugar errado ela deveria estar antes da primeira `col-md-6`, depois vc precisa usar o mesmo `line-height` no elementos para ele ficarem alinhados...

Para ajustar o texto de forma a ficar alinhado o primeiro a esquerda em telas grande e o outro a direita em telas grande vc pode usar alinhamentos em `flex` para a `UL` e com `text-align` para a `col-md-6`

Alinhamento com texto: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/
Alinhamento do flex: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficaria algo como isso para alinhar a direita e a esquerda e depois em telas pequena coloca tudo centralizado como na imagem acima.

```
<div class=" col-md-6 text-center text-md-left">
<ul class="bottom_ul d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end">
```

Veja o resultado aqui: Exiba em **"Página toda"** já que vc está usando `col-md` só vai ficar duas coluna na mesma linha em telas maiores que `765px`

```css
.copyright p {
    line-height: 40px;
}

.bottom_ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.bottom_ul li {
    line-height: 40px;
}

.bottom_ul li:after {
    content: "/";
    color: #f00;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.bottom_ul li a {
    color: #f00;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="copyright">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-6 text-center text-md-left">
                <p>© Copyright @DateTime.Now.Year.- LMS/US-LOG/OLNF/TM</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul class="bottom_ul d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end">
                    <li><a target="_blank">GISSUB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SGMAR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Suporte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Chamados</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Recursos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela explicação tão detalhada. Sempre fui profissional backend, mas agora fui obrigado a pegar esse trabalho deixado por outra pessoa, então to tendo que me virar e to meio perdido rs

Comment: @Jhensen sem problemas no que eu puder ajudar eh só me dar o toque, mas a documentação do BS4 eh bem completa e tem classe nativa pra quase tudo! Boa sorte ai abs

Comment: Valeu! Aproveitando, como vc gerou esse gif, foi pelo chrome? que vc fez o teste da resolução?

Comment: Usei um programinha para Windows que chama ScreenToGif, para linux ou mac vc tem que procurar algo como "screen recorder" ou algo assim goolge